# Displaying user attributes with f.select in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to using this, so might be missing something. Anyways, when i have the code:

```
<%= f.label :student %> <%= f.select :student, current_user.students{|p| [ p.first_name, p.id ] } %>
```

The drop down menu appears with the user's encrypted names and not their names. I feel like I've added :first_name or .first_name to everything.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
<%= f.select :student, current_user.students.collect{|p| [ p.first_name, p.id ] } %>
```

*Or*

```
<%= f.select :student, current_user.students, :first_name, :id %>
```